# http content-range support in IIS

Tags: http, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am wondering whether IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008 has good support for HTTP `content-range` header?

Details about `content-range` can be found from:

> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-122

I want to use the `content-range` feature to implement a reliable upload mechanism, I'm not sure if it is feasible.

Here is some code I found when searching which which uses this mechanism, I'm not sure whether it is reliable and robust:

> http://www.cnblogs.com/westfruit/archive/2010/08/31/1813540.html

Comment: Probably belongs more on http://serverfault.com

Comment: I highly doubt content-range will work for uploads.

Comment: @leppie, why? Any more descriptions or documents to reference for not good support for uploading?